# Save data from game to editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Say I have a canvas with a panel on it. Obviously, whatever changes I make to the panel's position and size while in edit mode, will be what those properties are when I start the game, unless explicitly set to be otherwise.

But what if I want to do the opposite? Make changes during gameplay, and then (after either exiting play mode, or closing the game application), have them persist in the editor?

I know how to automatically save and load changes while playing -- how do I automatically load the saved values back into the editor version of the scene?

Comment: Basically, I don't think you can.  There are three workarounds I'm aware of:

 1. Copy the changed object while in play mode and then paste it once back in edit mode.
 2. Find a plugin that does basically the same thing.
 3. Change the UI settings so that it is really obvious you are in play mode and won't mistakenly exit without copying the settings.
The third item is what I do.

Comment: It can be done with an Editor plugin. See the duplicate for how to get started.

Comment: This is a feature the dev team is aware of and is working to implement it. I remember seeing a video at the unite conference a couple of years back about this exact issue. I believe they were working on a solution using ScriptableObject. Maybe look that up and see what progress they've made.